# cancel postback in linkbutton when binding to jquery click event

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, jquery

I have a linkbutton to which i am binding to the click event using jQuery, however the page still posts back no matter what i try...

According to [this](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) i should be able to use [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

However nothing seems to work and it always posts back, ***but i do get the alert***

Here is my example

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="TEST" ID="lnkTest"></asp:LinkButton>
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var lnk = $('#<%=this.lnkTest.ClientID %>');
        lnk.unbind('click.test').bind('click.test', function (event) { alert("Click"); event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); return false; });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Okay after some further investigation it seems that this does work as expected when i run it in a standalone page, however we are using [this](http://kenbrowning.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-jquery-to-standardize.html) script, and it appears that it is causing a conflict..

That script moves any href='javascript:... into the click handler, im guessing that the order the handlers are assigned may have something to do with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I've tried reproducing this without success. Anything else in your code that differs from [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/YMAUY/show/)?

Comment: Ahh yes. Totally forgot about those. I'll do some testing and see if I can reproduce this.